# Using Amazon SDK with NativeScript

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nativescript

I'm doing some testing with the Amazon SDK for Fire Phone for the purpose of learning use it on NativeScript.

I followed the setup instructions as described on the site (https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/ide-tools/tech-docs/01-setting-up-your-development-environment). But I made the changes to the `app.gladle` file in the App_resources / Android folder:

```
// Add your native dependencies here:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.amazon.device.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+'
    }
}

// Uncomment to add recyclerview-v7 dependency
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion = "Amazon.com:Amazon Fire Phone SDK Addon:17"
  defaultConfig {
    generatedDensities = []
    applicationId = "br.com.carlosdelfino.mobile.client"

    //override supported platforms
    // ndk {
    //       abiFilters.clear()
    //          abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        // }

  }
  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }

  //splits {
  //    abi {
  //      enable true //enables the ABIs split mechanism
  //      reset() //reset the list of ABIs to be included to an empty string
  //      include 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
  //      universalApk true
  //    }
  //}
}
```

And when I try to compile the application and run it, I get the following error:

```
client/platforms/android/libs/aar/Primitives-2017.1.324-dev-release.aar
    +adding dependency: /Users/carlosdelfino/workspace/client/platforms/android/libs/aar/widgets-release.aar

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'client'.
> failed to find target with hash string 'Amazon.com:Amazon Fire Phone SDK Addon:17' in: /Users/carlosdelfino/Library/Android/sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2 mins 44.264 secs
Processing node_modules failed. Error: Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1
```

Is this a problem specific to the Amazon SDK or NativeScript because I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: ""Amazon.com:Amazon Fire Phone SDK Addon:17" is not a valid Android SDK version. I would remove the `compileSdkVersion` entry, see if the amazon library compiles without it, or just input what I would compile the nativescript project with. To pinpoint a select compileSdk version from the NS CLI you can pass the `--compileSdk` flag with a value in the range of `22-26`. Usually you want to compile against the latest target to access the latest and greatest android bits.

Comment: @pkanev, Thank you.
I gave up the tests and went back to the original and everything is working fine.